# ‘Biscuit’ as modifier, according to the online OED

Tags: modifiers, dictionaries

If you look up the word ‘[biscuit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/biscuit)’ in the Oxford online dictionary, you'll see this

> **biscuit**
>
> noun
>   1   *British*      A small baked unleavened cake, typically crisp, flat, and sweet:
>   *[as modifier] ‘a chocolate biscuit’*
>       *More example sentences*     *Synonyms*

If a chocolate biscuit is a biscuit, albeit made with chocolate, shouldn't ‘chocolate’ be the modifier? This questions whether I really know what a modifier (or a chocolate biscuit) is. Or it's just an error.

---

Comparison with ‘[oil](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oil)’

> **oil**
>
> noun
>   [...]
>   1.1 Petroleum:
>       ‘400 birds were coated with oil which spilled out from an opened valve’
>   *[as modifier] ‘the oil industry’*

This is in agreement with the common definition of [grammatical modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier). I don't think ‘a chocolate biscuit’ is a modifier as a whole: it wouldn't be an example with ‘biscuit’ used as a modifier (and it wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: This is an error, probably a contamination from definition 2.

Comment: @Human FYI in America this baked good is called a "cookie".  [This is a "biscuit"](http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/250x250/1001596.jpg), and not ordinarily paired with chocolate.

Comment: You are correct, the Oxford is wrong (as it is often is nowadays). Your example _chocolate biscuit_ is a noun phrase, in which the nominal _chocolate_ modifies the head of the NP _biscuit_.

Comment: @Andrew, something has happened to you comment: it was not directed to me...

Comment: @Human it looks like someone moderated the comments ... but anyway mine is just information, only indirectly related to your question.  You might want to check out this page of [British vs. American terms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/british-and-american-terms).   Plus, Australia have a bunch more all their own.

Comment: That's not the OED.  It's from Oxford, but it's a completely different dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

'Tis simply an error. Nouns do not modify their adjectives (in the grammatical sense, of course; you parse the "dead" in "dead weight" far differently from "dead pet").

Answer (score -3):

In the example, both **chocolate** and **biscuit** are modifiers of the other. A chocolate biscuit is a biscuit, normally a [digestive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digestive_biscuit), with a layer of chocolate on one side. Thus you are eating chocolate that is on a biscuit (where *biscuit* modifies *chocolate*) and a biscuit that has chocolate on it (where *chocolate* modifies *biscuit*).

Comment: No, a chocolate biscuit on its own means a biscuit made of chocolate. What you say does not reflect English usage.

Comment: @Lambie [Chocolate biscuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate_biscuit).

Comment: chocolate and biscuit are NOT modifiers of each other.

Comment: How can they each be modifiers of each other?  That doesn't make sense.  In noun adjunct phrases, the first noun modifies the second, they don't modify each other.  A "race horse" is a kind of horse, and "race" tells us what kind of horse, but "horse" doesn't modify "race".